# No resource found that matches the given name android:windowEnterAnimation

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-styles

I'm trying to define a custom style for dialog:

```
<style name="FullScreenDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
  <!-- Additionally if you want animations when dialog opening -->
  <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in_left</item>
</style>
```

But I get these errors upon building: 
Failed to generate resource table for split ''

and

No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:windowEnterAnimation' with value '@anim/slide_in_left').

I looked `@anim/slide_in_left` from [android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.anim) so I don't know what am I missing.

The worst part for my android development experience is that I can't find a reference for these styles, there should be a reference for all the attributes defined in for example `Theme.AppCompat.Dialog` so I can browse them and their default values and decide that I need to inherit and change some values, but I can't find the reference and in all questions in stack overflow and other sites just fixes are presented with no explanation of the fundamental issue and how to dig deeper, which is frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you define one custom style and want to use slide_in_left animation, the slide_in_left.xml is in anim folder in Resource folder, so there is anim folder--slide_in_left.xaml? like this:

[image]

According to your error message, I guess that you don't have anim and slide_in_left.xml file. Please check it.

Here is article about creating Xamarin Android Animating Activities, may be helpful to you.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-create-xamarin-andoird-animating-activities/

**Update:**

I guess that you want to use android default in style, if yes, you can do this:

```
<style name="FullScreenDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
<!-- Additionally if you want animations when dialog opening -->
<item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@android:anim/slide_in_left</item>
```

Comment: This works on android does that mean xamarin does not implement whole android sdk constants?

Comment: @mohas,If you want to use Android default animation,please look at my update.